# How to build Spark 1.6.1 with SBT on Windows using Hadoop profiles?

Tags: apache-spark, build, sbt, profiles

How can one activate Hadoop and YARN profiles while building Spark on Windows (8-10) with SBT?

```
>sbt package
```

The above code works, but could not activate profiles with the following:

```
>sbt -Pyarn package
```

I'm asking, because `mvn` is exceptionally slow compared to SBT. I have experience building Spark on Linux using both SBT and Maven.

Comment: I have two questions here. 1. Why you need to rebuild spark on Windows? Why not using one of the pre-built binary versions available in Spark site? 2. In Windows, how you try to start the sbt and the build process? are you using PowerShell, Cygwin for example?

Comment: Answering the first question usually leads to a huge argument about "why would you do what you would like to do", so I'll just avoid that if you don't mind. I just invoke the `sbt` command from a simple terminal.

Comment: I would recommend the same thing mentioned in @Vitaliy Kotlyarenko , sbt is not meant to support maven profiles, so you need to use the sbt comes with the Spark source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `./build/sbt` script bundled with Spark source distribution. It calls another script `sbt-launch-lib.bash` that does some profile-related magic:

```
enableProfile () {
  dlog "[enableProfile] arg = '$1'"
  maven_profiles=( "${maven_profiles[@]}" "$1" )
  export SBT_MAVEN_PROFILES="${maven_profiles[@]}"
}
```

On the other side, project definition `SparkBuild` extends `PomBuild`, that allows usage of Maven project (including profiles):

```
override val profiles = {                                                                                                              
  val profiles = Properties.envOrNone("SBT_MAVEN_PROFILES") match {                                                                    
    ...
  }                                                                                                                             
  profiles                                                                                                                             
}
```

So it should work if you run it like this (using Cygwin):

```
sh build/sbt -Pyarn package
```

Nevertheless, it didn't work for me out of the box because of incorrect discovery of path to `sbt-launch-lib.bash`. So I've replaced in `build\sbt` one line:

```
. "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"/sbt-launch-lib.bash
```

to

```
. "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"/build/sbt-launch-lib.bash
```